# List & tuple aren't working despite addressing `django.core.excptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The TEMPLATE_DIRS setting must be a list or a tuple` error

Tags: django

I've been hitting a snag with my Django app. Running Python manage.py runserver in my development environment, I get this error:
`django.core.excptions.ImproperlyConfigured. The TEMPLATE_DIRS setting must be a list or a tuple`. After changing `TEMPLATE_DIRS` to a tuple in settings.py as this `TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),)` I got :

```
TypeError('Invalid path type: %s' % type(value).__name__)TypeError: Invalid path type: tuple.
```

I got a similar response when I changed it to a list.
Meanwhile, running Python manage.py runserver outside the development environment I got:

`expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple on both times I changed TEMPLATE_DIRS to a list and tuple`.

I should also add that my template files aren't loading. I get:

> Using the URLconf defined in myProject.urls, Django tried these URL
> patterns, in this order:
>
> ```
> accounts/
>
> admin/
>
> The current path, index/, didn't match any of these
> ```

Here is the project tree:

```
|_______myApp
|______ |______pycache__
|   |______migrations
|   |________init__
|   |______admin
|   |______apps
|   |______models
|   |______tests
|   |______urls
|   |______views
|______myProject
|   |________init__
|   |______asgi
|   |______settings
|   |______urls
|   |______wsgi
|______env
|______static
|______templates
    |______myApp
        |______index.html
        |______signup.html
manage.py
```

myProject/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path 

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), 
]
```

myApp/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    ]
```

views.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),   
]
```

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), ]
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIRS],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ], },  },]
```

I don't know how else to fix it.

Comment: Use `'DIRS': TEMPLATE_DIRS,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TEMPLATE_DIRS` is *already* a list, so it makes no sense to wrap that again in the list, you should define the `TEMPLATES` setting as:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # …,
        'DIRS': TEMPLATE_DIRS,
        # …
    }
  ]
```